# Call multiple AsyncTask at a time not working in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to call multiple `AsynTask`. It was not working so I google for some help. I found that If I use `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` then it will work.

But It is not working.

I am calling it as below:

```
new GetCategory().execute();
new GetArea().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Please help me regarding this issue. I want to call it at a time or it is also ok if `GetArea()` call after `GetCategory()`.
I am not getting error. Application may be doing too much work.
**Logcat:**

```
03-13 21:21:43.134: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:43.394: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:43.634: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:43.784: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:44.004: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:44.164: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:45.495: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:45.765: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:46.005: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:46.235: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:46.525: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:46.855: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:47.005: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:47.156: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 21:21:47.306: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I am binding Spinner on both `AsynTask`.
**My Code :**

```
        Area[] areaList = gson.fromJson(result, Area[].class);

        List<Area> lList = Arrays.asList(areaList);
        Area objArea;

        areaId.add("0");
        areaName.add("Select Area");

        for (int i = 0; i < lList.size(); i++) {
            objArea = lList.get(i);
            areaName.add(objArea.getAreaName());
            areaId.add(objArea.getAreaId());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, areaName);
                ((Spinner) spnCEArea).setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problem *really* is. Right now, it appears that you are just guessing.

Comment: this is not working if you post like this

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you can't call two `.execute()` methods on `AsyncTask` within the same project at the same time is the modification that Android introduced since `Gingerbread`. Up until this version, you were able to call `.execute()` as many times you needed as each of them were run in a separate `Thread`.

But as of this version, they're called sequentially so if one is executing, the other one won't start if you just call `.execute()`.

So basically all you need to do is to check the version of the device you're running the `AsyncTask` on and run one or other command depending at it.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
  your_asynctask.execute(your_params);
else
  your_asynctask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, your_params);
```

More info [here](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/).

By the way, the `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` lines are not related to the `AsyncTask`. These tasks are being run in background and if you're doing the work within your `doInBackground()` method, it's not the issue.

A slightly different case might be if you're doing some work in your `onPostExecute()` task, as this might be related to your main UI, but we can't tell you more without knowing the code you're running.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working. even I removed code from onPostExecute() but same problem.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Is the second `AsyncTask` executed? Is it still having frames skipped, or what? If so, you should update your question and post your code, we're guessing blindly.

Comment: Where's that code placed in? Is it a function of a class, an `AsyncTask` or what?

Comment: you can read line above code, it is at onPostExecute() of AsyncTask.

Comment: Seems that your're initializing an `ArrayAdapter` from within your `onPostExecute` method. As I said previously, this method is linked with the main UI so you really are running that work there, that's why you're seeing that frames being skipped. Depending on how complex is your `ArrayAdapter`, this is probably the issue, but it doesn't have to do with your **background** method (`doInBackground()`) which is exclusively run outside of your main UI thread. Try seeing what could be taking too much to your `getView()` method and use `ViewHolder`s if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

```
@Override
public void doInBackground(params.....){

        //Your other code goes here

            Area[] areaList = gson.fromJson(result, Area[].class);

            List<Area> lList = Arrays.asList(areaList);
            Area objArea;

            areaId.add("0");
            areaName.add("Select Area");

            for (int i = 0; i < lList.size(); i++) {
                objArea = lList.get(i);
                areaName.add(objArea.getAreaName());
                areaId.add(objArea.getAreaId());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, areaName);

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Params..){


                ((Spinner) spnCEArea).setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In this way, you place all your workload in doInBackground and just fitting adapter to listView in onPostExecute. This is the right way to do. And I am sure it solves the issue.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Give me some time. I will check it out and let you know.

Comment: Sure. Give it a shot.

Comment: Sorry to say but still same logcat. Application is doing too much work.

Comment: your mean after problem solved ? As I have done nothing new, It is same as Call second AsyncTask() on first AsyncTask()'s OnPostExecute().

Comment: No need to create another aysnctask. Please check my edited answer. If this didn't help, there is somewhere wrong in other part of your code. Not here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to use 2 asynctasks with :

```
new GetCategory().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"");
new GetArea().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"");
```

If it doesn't work and crashes, post your logcat. If it does post your code.

Comment: this is not working. Application is doing too much work.

Comment: With those logcat messages I assume you are using an emulator? If so, you can ignore this. If you want to be sure if something works test it on a real device

Comment: yes, I am using emulator. Let me try on real device.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
Executor exec = AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR;

new GetCategory().executeOnExecutor(exec);
new GetArea().executeOnExecutor(exec);
```

But read the warning here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Params...)
It's probably not what you want.

Comment: You are giving way too little info.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to have multiple AsyncTask run one after the other is using the SERIAL_EXECUTOR
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR

Basically:

```
new GetCategory().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
new GetArea().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: Not Usefull , Tried this too, But doInBackground not being called after calling 4 or 5 time !

Comment: It was helpful in the context (and about 6 years ago!), you have a different issue and I suggest to open a question for it.

Answer (score 0):

if you do want both tasks to happen now - and not sequentially - then simply make one of them run as a thread instead of an AsyncTask