# How to run multiple threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

How to run multiple thread in android.  i read that from honeycomb  we can run 5 asynctask threads parallel. Is there any limitation in size of thread? if so, how can i run x thread parallel.

Comment: post the code pls. use executor

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383604/call-multiple-asynctask-at-a-time-not-working-in-android/22426432#22426432

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy to find it on Google.

Here a way to run thread :

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                // work
                sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: @Raghunandan: for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) 
 {
 new photodownload().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, i);
 }